# A-t-on un équivalent de « don't let the door hit you on the way out » ?

Tags: anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

La locution « [don't let the door hit you on the way out](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/don%27t_let_the_door_hit_you_on_the_way_out) » est employée pour signifier qu'on est heureux, ou du moins indifférent, de voir la personne à qui elle est destinée, partir (basé sur la définition au *Wiktionary*).

A-t-on une expression idiomatique en français qui s'en approche (hormis *bon débarras/vent* pour [*good riddance*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/good_riddance#English), une expression synonyme) ?

Answer (score 6):

Deux propositions :

- *Je ne vous montre pas la sortie*

et

- *(Je ne vous raccompagne pas), vous connaissez la sortie*. (cf. commentaire @Archemar)

Inspiré par @Mitch :

- *N'oublie pas de fermer la porte (derrière toi) !*

Comment: Ouais, merci, j'ai pas pensé à ça, je suis centré sur la porte qui frappe. D'ailleurs j'aurais dit _la porte est là_ dans le sens de tes propositions.

Comment: on peut préfixer la deuxième proposition par : je vous raccompagne pas, ...

Answer (score 0):

Une proposition familière:

- *Va voir ailleurs si j'y suis!*